# people picker gives error custommembershipprovider no exact match

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, peoplepicker

In my sharepoint project i have list(meeting) and it has a column named as participant

the participant column type is "person or group"

and in 'my meeting add page' this column is represented as a people picker textbox.

but when i try to add a new user in this box i m getting custommembershipprovider:no exacth match error

i attached the picture of the situtation. by the way this project is not written by me and i m new in sharepoint.

not: two days ago it was working. then we went into iis manager. we changed the identity of some application pools. I think the reason is this. but i do not know how to fix it since i do not know what it should be.

so what can be the possible problems.[image]

in addition to this for sharepoint web sites there are a lot of application pool. what was the configration of this? [image]

Comment: Changing the apppool user on sharepoint a pretty bad idea, because usually, this user has been configured during installation and has several privileges on high important services. I suggest you restoring the users back.

Comment: I forgot to mention that your error seems to point out a problem with membership, are you using fba? did you check if the account you, or someone else, changed, was also the account used to configure fba?

Comment: i do not know am i using fba or not. how to check what am i using? can you please help me

Comment: FBA is to authenticate on Sharepoint using a login form instead of the default setting (windows authentication). is this the case?